# Unable to mount HDD and concerns over the partition setup

Tags: ubuntu, mount, hard-disk, partition-table, smartctl

**Final Edit**
A quick note to say thanks for the comments, I certainly learned a lot. Unfortunately, having decided to return the HDD they tested it themselves and concluded that the device was faulty.

I recently bought an internal 4TB HDD to add to a Ubuntu machine. This is my first attempt at adding an HDD to an established machine and mounting it to a specific location. Unfortunately, I'm running into some problems and all similar posts I've seen haven't quite resolved my issue. Therefore, I will try and give a complete breakdown of the steps I understood, followed and the errors I'm facing.

My version of Ubuntu:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Firstly, after many failed efforts at adding a partition to the HDD and mounting the HDD I've killed the table so consider this as my baseline:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1M count=10
```

The disk is /dev/sdc

When I use lsblk this is the output (sdc is at the bottom):

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2074
loop1    7:1    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop2    7:2    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop3    7:3    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop4    7:4    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop5    7:5    0  65.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
loop6    7:6    0  65.2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
loop7    7:7    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/542
loop8    7:8    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/547
loop9    7:9    0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/13170
loop10   7:10   0  32.4M  1 loop /snap/snapd/13270
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0 465.3G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   116M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0   506M  0 part 
└─sdb3   8:19   0 930.9G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 from
```

And with sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MG03ACA4
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I then use gdisk (I have tried using `parted`) to assign a partition table with type and name etc.

Adding a new partition:

```
Command (? for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 1
First sector (34-7814037134, default = 2048) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 2048
Last sector (2048-7814037134, default = 7814037134) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 7814037134
Current type is 8300 (Linux filesystem)
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): 
Changed type of partition to 'Linux filesystem'
```

Let's look at it with `p` (print)

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      7814037134   3.6 TiB     8300  Linux filesystem
```

I want to call it store:

```
Command (? for help): c store
Using 1
Enter name: store
```

(after a print)

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      7814037134   3.6 TiB     8300  store
```

Finally write the partition table to disk and exit (with `w`):

```
Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): Y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sdc.
The operation has completed successfully.
```

Let's look at the drives and mount points again (`lsblk`):

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2074
loop1    7:1    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop2    7:2    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop3    7:3    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop4    7:4    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop5    7:5    0  65.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
loop6    7:6    0  65.2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
loop7    7:7    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/542
loop8    7:8    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/547
loop9    7:9    0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/13170
loop10   7:10   0  32.4M  1 loop /snap/snapd/13270
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0 465.3G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   116M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0   506M  0 part 
└─sdb3   8:19   0 930.9G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0   3.7T  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I now want to mount my drive to a location called /store (yes, the same name as the partition on sdc1 - I hope that isn't confusing). This is where I run into an error:

```
(base) anthony@Shodan:/dev$ sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdc1 /store
mount: /store: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I am really not sure what to do from here. I've repeated the same process above but using parted. The steps are successful but again it fails when I try mounting.

**EDIT #1**
Thanks for the comments. Turns out I didn't create a filesystem so I executed the following but had an error:

```
(base) anthony@Shodan:~$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1
[sudo] password for anthony: 
mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Creating filesystem with 976754385 4k blocks and 244195328 inodes
Filesystem UUID: d6b2219f-b4fe-490b-bf21-513fec50c625
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
    102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (262144 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: mkfs.ext4: Input/output error while writing out and closing file system
```

I then install smartmodtools and used smartctl to test the new drive but I ran into a further problem:

```
(base) anthony@Shodan:~$ sudo smartctl --smart=on -T permissive /dev/sdc
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.11.0-37-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Short INQUIRY response, skip product id
=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
unable to fetch IEC (SMART) mode page [scsi response fails sanity test]
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

**EDIT #2**
I'm still struggling to get this drive to work. The disk support SMART (just checked BIOS), and this is what the kernel sees:

```
(base) anthony@Shodan:/$ dmesg | egrep -i "sdc"
[    1.696642] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[    1.696658] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[    1.696661] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.696680] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.930394]  sdc: sdc1
[    1.943940] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[ 2857.111158] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=90s
[ 2857.111168] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 35 c0 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 2857.111172] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 901777408 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[ 2857.111184] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 901775360, lost async page write
[ 2857.111191] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 901775361, lost async page write
[ 2857.111199] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 901775362, lost async page write
[ 2857.111204] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 901775363, lost async page write
[ 2857.111208] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 901775364, lost async page write
[ 2857.111212] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 901775365, lost async page write
[ 2857.111215] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 901775366, lost async page write
[ 2857.111223] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 901775367, lost async page write
[ 2857.111365] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2857.111370] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 2857.111371] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 905971712 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[ 2857.111375] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 905969664, lost async page write
[ 2857.111378] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 905969665, lost async page write
[ 2857.111407] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2857.111410] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 36 40 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 2857.111410] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 910166016 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[ 2857.111430] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2857.111432] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 36 80 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 2857.111433] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 914360320 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[ 2857.111451] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2857.111453] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 36 c0 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 2857.111454] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 918554624 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[ 2857.111471] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2857.111473] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 37 00 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 2857.111474] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 922748928 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[ 2857.111484] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2857.111486] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 37 40 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 2857.111487] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 926943232 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[ 2857.111517] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2857.111520] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 37 80 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 2857.111521] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 931137536 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[ 2857.111539] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2857.111541] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 37 c0 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 2857.111542] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 935331840 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[ 2857.111567] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2857.111569] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 38 00 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 2857.111570] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 939526144 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[ 3053.218272] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 3053.218285] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
[ 3638.943105] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 3638.943112] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 2c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
[ 3653.216166] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 3653.216179] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
[ 3971.568186] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 3971.568192] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Synchronize Cache(10) 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[ 3971.568197] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
[ 3971.568235] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 3971.568237] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00
[ 3971.568238] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
[ 3971.568256] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 3971.568258] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 3971.568259] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 3971.568262] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 3971.568276] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 3971.568278] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 3971.568279] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 3971.568281] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 3971.569093] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3971.569103] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 3971.569160] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3971.569164] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 3971.569203] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 3971.569280] sdc: detected capacity change from 7814037168 to 0
[ 4048.513170] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 4048.513175] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 4048.513197] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 4048.513198] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 4053.558167] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 4053.558170] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 4053.558188] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 4053.558189] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 4253.213080] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 4253.213094] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
[ 4853.209760] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 4853.209774] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
```

Comment: There also now are two labels with gpt partitioned drives. One is GUID(gpt) partition label & other is the formatted partition label. You can see both with `lsblk -e7  -o FSTYPE,NAME,LABEL,PARTLABEL,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT` And to add to use of labels, parted uses mklabel as command to set drive to gpt (or msdos).

Comment: @oldfred Thanks for your comment. I'm fairly new at disk management and I'm afraid I don't quite understand. From the output I included, where are the two labels with gpt partitioned drives? Thanks.

Comment: Added further information in the first edit.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't create a [filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) on the partition, you need one to be able to mount it. You probably want [Ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) (default for most distributions, if you are dualbooting with Windows, NTFS would a be better choice) so simply run `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1` and after that you can mount `sdc1`.

Comment: Thank you! On executing mkdf.ext4 I get the following:
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: mkfs.ext4: Input/output error while writing out and closing file system

Comment: The I/O errors usually mean hardware failure, if it's a new HDD it could be a cable or loose connection issue. Try [SMART](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/S.M.A.R.T.) test and check logs for more errors.

Comment: All new territory. I tried SMART and it kicks out the following error when I just print disk info:
Read defect list: asked for grown list but didn't get it
Error Counter logging not supported

Device does not support Self Test logging

Comment: Added further information in the first edit.

Comment: Internal or external drive? USB3 adapters do not always support all features like an internal drive. Some do not even fully support gpt or large drives. I create mount point & mount using that for permanent mounts. But label everything else, so auto mount uses label. But also am converting to use labels for some other mounts. I now try to avoid using UUID except for system mounts that are created automatically. But I have labeled partition as Data, but created mount data. Those are different as Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: It's an internal drive. Thanks for this information, it's helpful.